# How to call service from different file in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I know almost same kind of question is answered in couple of other posts but I'm getting "Unknown provider" error on calling service written in different file then callee Controller function. Could some one please help me to know what am I doing wrong? Here is my code

**Controller.js**

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.controller("PromoList", ['$scope', '$http', 'modelSerivce', function ($scope, $http, modelSerivce){
var serviceURL = modelSerivce.serviceURL();
console.log("from promolist controller: "+ serviceURL);}]);
```

**Service.js**

```
angular.module('mainApp').service('modelSerivce', function(){       
this.serviceURL = function()
{
    var serviceURL = “cofig.xml”;
    return serviceURL;
};});
```

Comment: Are you including `Service.js` in your HTML?

Comment: And if you are including `Service.js` is it included AFTER Controller.js? This ensures that you have created your module, `mainApp`, before referencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you reference `Service.js` in your .html file?

Comment: Oh yeah I missed referencing Services.js in html and that worked!! Thanks a ton !!!

Comment: Anytime! Glad I helped :)